# JS Шахматы

Tags: html, php, javascript

Уважаемые программисты и любители программирования! Я разрабатываю сетевую версию игры "Шахматы" в JS и у меня есть 2 доски...одна где двигаются только белые...вторая где двигаются только черные...проблема в том чтобы эти доски взаимодействовали друг с другом, тоесть передвинул на одной доске белую фигуру на второй автоматически белая фигура становится в этуже клетку...я не прошу написанного программного кода, а прошу помочь советом или идеей как это осуществить...заранее спасибо!!!

Comment: А зачем две доски?

Comment: Ну, у вас же есть центральный сервер? Пусть при ходе на одной доске отправляется ход на сервер, там он проверяется на правильность, и другая доска получает обновление (например, через longpoll).

Comment: @Photon: например, чтобы в шахматы играли два человека, не сидящие на одном хосте?

Comment: там у каждой доски своя кнопка записи в базу ходов, тоесть у белых записывает в определенную ячейку в базе, а когда на доске с черными нажимается кнопка то в зу дописывается ход черных в ячейку рядом с белой, там есть несколько моментов благодаря которым я так сделал(((

Comment: @VladD, всё равно непонятно..  Если люди сидят на разных машинах, то каждый должен видеть одну доску..  На которой свой ход он делает сам, а чужой ход - просто видит.. Анимированно

Comment: ну, будет одна доска, и она будет обновляться

Comment: @MikeVin, это неправильно..  Надо писать ходы в базу в шахматной нотации..
Т.е. что-то типа: from=a2, to=a4 и уже потом парсить эти а2 или а4, если партия была прервана, а потом возобновлена

Comment: @Photon: ну да, я это и имел в виду. А в чём проблема? С сервера приходит информация только о ходах противника. Анимация -- совершенно ортогональная проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется проще каждой клетке дать уникальный ID, в бд должны быть текущие игры, а там инфа где стоит каждая фигурка и у какого игрока, допустим решил ты передвинуть фигурку, сразу идёт запрос в БД, изменяется положение этой фигурки, а у другого происходит авто обновление, через 1 сек, чтобы была проверка, ничего ли в случае там не поменялось в бд, если поменялось двигаем фигурку, можно сделать на Node.JS/MongoDB  чтобы статусы отсылались, также просто на php/js/mysql

Comment: Это всё пипец как неправильно..  Как, например, последовательность ходов партии в таком варианте отображать?

Answer (score 0):

Храните в базе нотацию партии одной строкой. В простейшем случае по таймеру каждый игрок получает эту строку и обрабатывает изменившийся "хвост" строки - это будет максимум один ход противника, который и надо будет анимировать.

При возобновлении игры по этой строке можно всегда воссоздать положение фигур с нуля (с анимацией или без)

Как вариант без базы, можно сделать игру на фреймах через postMessage (генерите одну доску и даете доступ к ней двум игрокам через iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так:

В БД сделал бы таблицу с полями:

- id партии
- номер хода
- черные или белые
- стартовая позиция
- конечная позиция

То есть партия будет выглядеть следующим образом:

- id 1 белые e2 e4
- id 2 Черные e7 e5

и так далее

Играющие общаются с сервером посредством webSocket, что бы не посылать запросы ежесекундно. Выглядит следующим образом:

- чел делает ход
- проверяем правильность хода
- отправляем emit на сервер
- сервер перепроверяет правильность и если все хорошо, отправляет ход в БД и второму игроку